# C++ dereference class attribute pointing to another class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dereference

I have 3 classes:

- Student
- Idea
- Game

The class student is a person. This person can generate Ideas of different types (games, car or some other type of idea).

So the Game class Extends the Idea class.

**Idea.h**

```
#ifndef SCHOOLGROUPS_IDEA_H
#define SCHOOLGROUPS_IDEA_H

#include <string>

class Student;

class Idea {
    friend bool addParticipants(Idea idea, Student* students);
public:
    Idea();
    Idea(std::string name, std::string description, std::string gameDesignDocumentLocation);

    Student* getLeader();

    virtual int printOut();
    Idea assignLeader(Student*);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string gameDesignDocumentLocation;
    Student* leader;
    Student* participants;
};


#endif //SCHOOLGROUPS_IDEA_H
```

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef SCHOOLGROUPS_GAME_H
#define SCHOOLGROUPS_GAME_H

#include "Idea.h"
#include <string>

class Game : public Idea {
public:
    Game();
    Game(std::string name, std::string description, std::string gameDesignDocumentLocation, std::string genre, unsigned ageRestriction);
    int printOut();
private:
    std::string genre;
    unsigned ageRestriction;
};


#endif //SCHOOLGROUPS_GAME_H
```

**Student.h**

```
#ifndef SCHOOLGROUPS_STUDENT_H
#define SCHOOLGROUPS_STUDENT_H

#include <string>
#include "Idea.h"

class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, unsigned age, std::string fNumber, std::string role);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Student* student);

    std::string getFirstName() const;
    std::string getLastName() const;
    unsigned getAge() const;
    std::string getFNumber() const;
    std::string getFullName() const;
    std::string getRole() const;
    Idea* getIdea() const;
    Idea* generateIdea(std::string name, std::string description, std::string document, std::string genre, unsigned ageRestriction);

private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    unsigned age;
    std::string fNumber;
    std::string role;
    Idea* idea;
};


#endif //SCHOOLGROUPS_STUDENT_H
```

I'm trying to overload the **<<** operator and when I use `this->getLeader()` to print out all the info I need for the leader (using the info from the student (first name, last name, etc..)

In the **Student.cpp** file I have the following code for the purpose:

```
#include <iostream>


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Student& student) {
    stream << "Name: " << student.getFullName() << std::endl;
    stream << "Role: " << student.getRole() << std::endl;

    return stream;
}
```

When I'm printing the info for the Idea I use the following code

```
/**
 * Print out details for the idea of the person
 *
 * @return int
 */
int Idea::printOut() {
    std::cout << "Title: " << this->name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Description: " << this->description << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Game Design Document: " << this->gameDesignDocumentLocation << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->leader << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `std::cout << this->leader << std::endl;` is where I'm trying to use the operator overloading. My problem is that the leader property of the class **Idea** is a pointer to the actual **Student** class. So in the end I get something like this:

```
Title: Tower Defense Game
Description: A game where you build towers and prevent waves from reaching a certain point
Game Design Document: ./gd.docx
0x16d3632c8 <--- This is the leader part, where I get the pointer to the memory.
Genre: Strategy Game
Age Restriction: 15
```

I tried to dereference it, but I've never made it.

- What is the best way to do this?
- How should I approach it?
- Is this the best way to keep info about the classes?
- Does my getLeader return the right type of information, should I dereference it there?

I'm kinda new to C++, just learning it in the University, not gonna lie, pointer are pretty hard for me. Whenever I think I understand them, they show me how much I don't know about them :D.

Comment: Pop quiz: when you have a pointer how do you access the pointed-to address? Hint: it's a single character.

Comment: You use the & operator?

Comment: No, that takes the address of an object, giving you the pointer. When you have a pointer, how do you go the other way, how do you get to the object?

Comment: Here is a little example I wrote with 1 integer and dereferencing it.

https://onlinegdb.com/4G-GUW5VI

Comment: I've tried to dereference the property of the class to return the Student, but I get the following warning https://i.imgur.com/grE8DbG.png. And `Incomplete result type 'Student' in function definition`

Comment: And which specific part of this error message is unclear to you? Is the `Student` class defined, before this function?

Comment: I mean I think I need to return a reference to the student a do the method like this
https://i.imgur.com/2UWDYVa.png and convert the pointer back to Student and return a Student& reference, but then the operator overloading is not working fine. I'm not sure where exactly is my problem.

`error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Student')
    std::cout << this->getLeader() << std::endl;`

Comment: Your problem is that you did not define an overloaded `<<` operator, that takes these parameters.

Comment: I have it defined in the Student.cpp, but I'm calling the overloading in the Game.cpp. So I guess that they do not know about each other in terms of scope, that is normal. So I moved the declaration in the Game.cpp https://i.imgur.com/Z9EDmto.png. and I get the error:

`error: member access into incomplete type 'Student' stream << "Name: " << student.getFullName() << std::endl;`

I forgot to include the header file of the "Student.h" in the Game.cpp ... Thank you for the help and making my brain move..

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **Sam Varshavchik** (Thank you!). I've managed to find the mistake and it's the following.

I had to dereference the **this->leader** property of the **Idea object** and return it like this:

```
Student& Idea::getLeader() {
    return *this->leader;
}
```

So after dereferencing the `*this->leader` I'm left with a reference to **Student** that I need to return to work with.